# Android MMS code specific?

Tags: android, mms

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra("address","5554);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
```

I have already given the receiver number programatically. Now I wanted only the "Send MMS" button event here. So can I handle it in code itself? My aim is disabling UI in this context. Is this achievable?

Is  there anyway for attaching image without using intent??
Plz help.

Answer (score 1):

Using "Intent.ACTION_SEND" will launch SMS/MMS applications. I think that is not what you want.
MMS is a http post request. You have to implement in another way.

Comment: Can u help me in this aspect??

Answer (score 0):

you will need to create member of type Activity which should injected in this class as constructor method or setter and within  that context if you try your function it might solve.i have successfully send sms by this way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Is sending MMS possible this way?? Please share your code.

Comment: i have only worked for sms.i am not sure if it use http post request.